# How to fix a 1054 error in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting this error:1054 Unknown column 'published' in 'where clause' 
SQL=

```
SELECT *
FROM by3f7_wf_profiles
WHERE published = 1
ORDER BY ordering ASC
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Specify a column defined in the table.

Comment: Is that column in that table?  Have you checked the spelling of the column name?  Is `published` just part of a wider field name, e.g. `wf_published`?

Answer (score 0):

The error is mostly what it says on the tin: MySQL couldn't find a column called `published` in that table.

Try executing `DESCRIBE by3f7_wf_profiles;` and see if the output matches what you expect, specifically look for the `published` column, its spelling, and type.

Comment: I figured it out. It was missing an old WordPress column and I was able to upload an older backup that still had it. I was pulling my hair out because I am not a MYSQL expert (yet) -- lol. But thanks for the tips.